# Node js Deploiement Plesk Error: age/Spa/SpawnEnvSetupperMain.cpp:747 ]: shellName = 'false' detected as supporting '-l': false

Tags: node.js, plesk

I have this error when i deploy my node js application in plesk Server

 I don't understund this problem:
"age/Spa/SpawnEnvSetupperMain.cpp:747 ]: shellName = 'false' detected as supporting '-l': false"

 someone can help me please [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKYH2.png)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

For Angular Universal I have figured it out:

The cause is in the `server.ts`: The `if` statement at the bottom of the file disallow the function `run()` to run. Basically, the value of `moduleFilename` doesn't match the `fileName` that normally matches in our local environment.

What I did, is to remove that `if` and replace the entire block with the following.
This doesn't block serving the app in ssr mode (`yarn dev:ssr`) in local machines.

```js
...

function run(): void {
    console.info("Starting up the Node server...");
    const server = app();
    const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;
    server.listen(port);
    console.info(`Node Express listening on port ${port}`);
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
// declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
// const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
// const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
run();
```

We can see the info log in passenger.log in Plesk.

```
App 991867 output: 991867/T1 age/Spa/SpawnEnvSetupperMain.cpp:747: shellName = 'bash' detected as supporting '-l': true
> Normally here, it stops logging and you will see a timout error. By removing the if statement server starts and you see more logs.
App 991867 output: Starting up the Node server...
App 991867 output: Node Express listening on port 443
```

Also, you can log `moduleFilename` and see what is inside and why is safe to delete the if statement with all those conditions.
Angular devs don't listen to us and we have to struggle until one comes with a solution.